# How to get models that inherit a given model in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-17

Odoo's `ir.model` defines the following field

```py
inherited_model_ids = fields.Many2many('ir.model', compute='_inherited_models', string="Inherited models",
                                           help="The list of models that extends the current model.")
```

From this definition I would expect to get a list all models that inherit the `mail.thread` model, for example, but I'm getting an empty recordset

```
>>> self.env['ir.model'].search([('model','=','mail.thread')]).inherited_model_ids
ir.model()
>>> self.env['ir.model'].search([('model','=','res.partner')]).inherited_model_ids
ir.model()
```

Maybe I don't understand how this works,.. I would appreciate if anyone could clearify

**EDIT**

Upon further investigation, `_inherited_models` seems to be doing something different from what I understood from the description of `inherited_model_ids`

```py
@api.depends()
def _inherited_models(self):
    self.inherited_model_ids = False
    for model in self:
        parent_names = list(self.env[model.model]._inherits)
        if parent_names:
            model.inherited_model_ids = self.search([('model', 'in', parent_names)])
        else:
            model.inherited_model_ids = False
```

Instead, it computes the models that the current model extends (it's parents as opposed to it's children), for example

```
>>> self.env['ir.model'].search([('model','=','res.users')]).inherited_model_ids
ir.model(85,) # res.partner
```

Also, it apparently only considers models extended using `_inherits`

This all seems a bit confusing to me!

However, I was able to get away with this

```py
self.env.cr.execute(
    """
        SELECT m.model from ir_model_inherit mi 
        JOIN ir_model m ON m.id = mi.model_id 
        WHERE mi.parent_id = %s 
    """,
    (parent_model_id.id,),
)
child_model_ids = self.env.cr.fetchall()
```